# What is the difference between .vscode/settings.json and .code-workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

could you please explain me what is the difference between `.vscode/settings.json` and `[project_name].code-workspace`?

I assume I can save setting for the specific project/workspace there. When I create a new workspace, file `[project_name].code-workspace` is automatically created and I can define project specific settings in there.

But what is then the difference to `.vscode/settings.json` and how can I use that? If I create that manually in a workspace, it just does not seem to work and settings inside are not applied.

Thank you

Comment: Read the doc on `Multi Root Workspace`